# Expectation and maximum

Tags: probability

Given random variables $X_1, \dots, X_n$. is there always a big-small relation between $\mathrm{E} \max\{X_1, \dots, X_n\}$ and $\max\{\mathrm{E} X_1, \dots, \mathrm{E} X_n\}$? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Just notice the max function is convex. Then the comparison is just an application of Jensen's inequality.

Comment: Thanks. (1) the max function has arbitrarily finitely many arguments. How is it convex in its arguments? (2) What if it is supremum instead of maximum, and the set of r.v.s can be arbitrarily many (countable or uncountable)?

Comment: $max\{x_1,\cdots,x_n\}=max\{f_1(x),\cdots,f_n(x)\}$ where each $f_i:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ and $f_i(x)=x_i$ the $i$th coordinate of $x$. Each $f_i$ is convex and nondecreasing, then the max function is convex.

Comment: Thanks. what about (2) added in my comment

Answer (score 2):

since $$\max\{X_i, i = 1,2,\cdots, n\} \geq X_k, \forall k = 1,2,\cdots,n$$
we have $$E\max\{X_i, i = 1,2,\cdots, n\} \geq EX_k, \forall k = 1,2,\cdots,n$$

then since  $b \geq a_k \implies b \geq \max a_k$, we have 
$$E\max\{X_i, i = 1,2,\cdots, n\} \geq \max\{EX_k, k = 1,2,\cdots,n\}$$

Comment: Thanks. What if it is supremum instead of maximum, and the set of r.v.s can be arbitrarily many (countable or uncountable)?

Comment: @Tim It it is supremum, the result still holds. Because we still have $$\sup X_i \geq X_k \implies E \sup X_i \geq EX_k \implies E \sup X_i \geq \sup EX_k $$